# Silverstripe - Setting Permissions for Front End pages

Tags: permissions, silverstripe

Trying to set permissions so that only a certain group of users can access certain pages on the front end. They don't need CMS access at all.

I have followed the [permissions guide](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/security/permissions/) on Silverstripe but I am not sure how to assign a specific group to only see specific pages.

This denies access to everyone except admins:

```
public function init() {
parent::init();
if(!Permission::check("VIEW_SITE")) Security::permissionFailure();
}

public function providePermissions() {
return array(
  "VIEW_SITE" => "Access the site",
);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To restrict access to certain pages based on what `Group`s they're in you can use `Member::inGroup` either in the model's `canView` function like so:

```php
public function canView($member = null) {

    if (!$member) {
        $member = Member::currentUser();
    }

    return Permission::check('ADMIN') || ($member && $member->inGroup('MyGroup'));

}
```

or in the controller's `init` function like so:

```php
public function init()
{
    parent:init();

    $member  = Member::currentUser();
    $canView = Permission::check('ADMIN') || ($member && $member->inGroup('MyGroup'));

    if (!$canView) {
        Security::permissionFailure();
    }
}
```

It's also possible and possibly preferable to instead use `Permission`s (like in your question) by creating specific `Permission`s for specific pages. E.g `VIEW_ACCOUNT_PAGE` for an account page, and then apply this `Permission` to all the `Group`s you want to have access to the account page (in the CMS under Security -> Groups -> Group X -> Permissions). You can then restrict access as such:

```php
# In AccountPage_Controller
public function init()
{
    parent:init();

    $canView = Permission::check('ADMIN') || Permission::check('VIEW_ACCOUNT_PAGE');

    if (!$canView) {
        Security::permissionFailure();
    }
}

public function providePermissions() 
{
    return [
        'VIEW_ACCOUNT_PAGE' => 'View account page',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I am using routes for my site. So I am just using controllers.

Comment: You can place the same logic in the controller's `init` function. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Excellent answer!